# getting last four quater data based on value from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables, table1 contains quater and week value and table2 contains data, I want show last four quater data based on value from table1
for example

Table1 (Will have only single row)

```
Week   Quater  
W3     Q22015
```

Table2

```
Quater  Column1 ColumnN  
Q12015  X11     Y11  
Q12014  X1      Y1  
Q22014  X2      Y3  
Q32014  X3      Y4  
Q42014  T1      Y5  
Q42013  3       Y7  
Q32013  5       7  
Q22013  6       8
```

Output data (since table1 has Q22015  so last four quarter data will be

```
Q12015
Q42014
Q32014
Q22014
```

Table3

```
Quater  Column1  ColumnN  
Q12015  X11      Y11  
Q22014  X2       Y3  
Q32014  X3       Y4  
Q42014  T1       Y5
```

also can I apply filter on both Quater and week if my table has week also Like W1, W2 , W3 etc than I want to show data for last four quarter plus data upto week which is mention in table1

Thanks

Comment: I'd start with fixing the data. `Q12015` isn't a great way to represent a quarter because it doesn't sort naturally, and the "Q" isn't necessary. Any solution would be a `SUBSTRING` monster. I recommend storing as `YYYYQ`: 1st quarter 2015 as `20151`, 2nd quarter 2015 as `20152`, etc. Similar issue with week, where the "W" isn't necessary.

Comment: Hi Gibbs, thanks, yes you are right, but actually I can only write select statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the values for quarted  in most proper way  for an easy select 
but stand actual situation you can manipulate the string and select this way

```
  select   Quater  , Column1  , ColumnN  
  from my_table
  where concat(substr(quater, -4 ), substr(quater,2,1))<= 
             (select concat(substr(quater, -4 ), substr(quater,2,1) from table1)
  and rownum <5
  order concat(substr(quater, -4 ), substr(quater,2,1))
```

and for getting all the result related to the last 4 quater

```
select Quater  , Column1  , ColumnN  
from my_table 
where quater in (

   select  quater from my_table 
    where concat(substr(quater, -4 ), substr(quater,2,1)) <= 
               (select concat(substr(quater, -4 ), substr(quater,2,1) from table1)
    and rownum <5
    order concat(substr(quater, -4 ), substr(quater,2,1))
)
order concat(substr(quater, -4 ), substr(quater,2,1))
```

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, thanks, Limit 4 is not working ( till order by query works), does oracle support Limit

Comment: @Russel   ..correct  answer  updated   with oracle is used  a filter on rownum

Comment: Hi scaisEdge, it is giving me top 4 rows, where as my requirement is getting all the data for last four quarter based on value in table1 ( I may have millinos reocrd in my table and it may conatin last 10 yers of data) but you have given me some start point I'll try to use it to get what I need.